# Publish events with MassTransit

Tags: masstransit

I'm trying to publish message in one **microservice** and get it in another one, but cannot implement this using **MassTransit** 5.5.3 with **RabbitMQ**.

As far as I know we don't have to create a **ReceiveEndpoint** to be able to publish event so I'm just creating the same message interface in both services and publish a message, but as I can see in **RabbitMQ** it either goes to nowhere (if doesn't mapped to a queue) or goes to "_skipped" queue.

Publisher:

```cs
namespace Publisher
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
            {
                IRabbitMqHost host = cfg.Host("host", "vhost", h =>
                {
                    h.Username("xxx");
                    h.Password("yyy");
                });
            });

            bus.Start();

            await bus.Publish<Message>(new { Text = "Hello World" });

            Console.ReadKey();

            bus.Stop();
        }
    }

    public interface Message
    {
        string Text { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Consumer:

```cs
namespace Consumer
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
            {
                IRabbitMqHost host = cfg.Host("host", "vhost", h =>
                {
                    h.Username("xxx");
                    h.Password("yyy");
                });

                cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, e =>
                {
                    e.Consumer<MbConsumer>();
                });
            });

            bus.Start();

            bool finish = false;

            while(!finish)
            {
                await Task.Delay(1000);
            }

            bus.Stop();
        }
    }

    public interface Message
    {
        string Text { get; set; }
    }

    public class MbConsumer : IConsumer<Message>
    {
        public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<Message> context)
        {
            await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync(context.Message.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm expeting the consumer to get the message once it's been published but it doesn't get it. I think this is because the full message types are different ("Publisher.Message" vs. "Consumer.Message") so message contract is different. How should I fix this code to get the event in the consumer? Looks like I'm missing some fundamental thing about **RabbitMQ** or **MassTransit**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your guess is correct. MassTransit uses the fully qualified class name as the message contract name. MassTransit also uses type-based routing, so FQCNs are used to create exchanges and bindings.

So, if you move your message class to a separate namespace like:

```
namespace Messages
{
    public interface Message
    {
        string Text { get; set; }
    }
}
```

You then can reference this type when you publish a message

```
await bus.Publish<Messages.Message>(new { Text = "Hello World" });
```

and define your consumer

```
public class MbConsumer : IConsumer<Messages.Message>
{
    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<Message> context)
    {
        await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync(context.Message.Text);
    }
}
```

it will work.

You might want also to look at RMQ management UI to find out about MassTransit topology. With your code, you will see two exchanges, one `Publisher.Message` and another one `Consumer.Message` where your consumer queue is bound to the `Consumer.Message` exchange, but you publish messages to the `Publisher.Message` exchange and they just vanish.

I would also suggest specifying a meaningful endpoint name for your receive endpoint:

```
cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "MyConsumer", e =>
{
    e.Consumer<MbConsumer>();
});
```

Comment: I don't specify the name because would like all consuming microservices to receive the message and handle appropriately, if we point out a queue name the event goes to only one of the services that would fit for competing consumer use case.

Comment: For competing consumers, you need to run several instances of the same service using the same queue name. As long as you run different services using different queue names, they all will get a message. You should not use random queue names, because if your service goes down, messages will be accumulating in the service queue and if the service will get another queue name, it will lose all pending messages and the queue gets stale.

Comment: what happens if I published a message and the consumer was not there (may be down). is there a setting that i can keep it in the publisher queue until the consumers come up and consume it from their own queues ?

Comment: If the consumer was there before, messages will accumulate in the queue. If the consumer wasn't there ever, messages will vanish. MassTransit creates exchanged, queues and bindings for consumers when the consumer application starts. After that messages will be delivered. It's all described in the docs.